# How to get dynamic template data from sendgrid api

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

I'm using Sendgrid API to get the list of all dynamic templates. I was a bit surprised when I saw  that the API response doesn't contain any info about the **dynamic template data**.

Is there a way to get the **dynamic template data** from sendgrid API ?

example: my dynamic template contains this dynamic data:

- {{ firstName }}
- {{ lastName }}
- {{ link }}

And I want to get this data back when querying sendgrid API:

[GET] [https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates/{{templateID}}](https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates/%7B%7BtemplateID%7D%7D)

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would also like to know if this is possible.

Comment: Hii.. did u find it out? i also need this solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the URL provided in the [Sendgrid Docs](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/transactional-templates/create-a-transactional-template) but with a special query parameter `?generations=dynamic`

Thus the final URL would look like this:

`https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates?generations=dynamic`

Very happy to find this, since I was also looking for it a long time.

Comment: I came back to my own answer half a year later. Glad I could help myself, again!